# How to Deal With Dapper return Key Value pair with Dynamic from LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dapper, dapper-extensions

I am new to Dapper. Let me explain what i am trying to achieve. I have simple query which is returning columns from DB, i don't want to create Entity(Property) class for it to fill the data. I want to use Dynamic Type for this. Below is my code:

```
public dynamic GetABC(int year)
    {

        using (var db = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ClsConnectionString.connectionString))
        {

            string query = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM ranking where YEAR(eventdate)='{0}') ORDER BY eventdate DESC, eventid ASC",year);
            //return db.Query<RankingEntity>(query, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text).AsList();
            var a = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)db.Query(query, null, null, true, null, CommandType.Text).ToList();
            return a;
       }
    }
```

It returns me Key Value pair. like below:
[image: Dapper Row]

Is there any way, i just write one common method to get List as "Property" = "Value" As normally we get when we use any Entity Class.

I am not sure, if it is achievable but i wish to learn if it is possible and want to implement in our application.

I can achieve this by implementing loop through the dapperrows which i don't want. because if there will be 10000 rows loop will iterate 10000 times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DapperRow is an internal class of the Dapper, which can be directly type- casted into `IDictionary<string,object>`, which has a key string and value object

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, could you please update the above code to get this. it would be better for to understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I have mentioned `DapperRow` is an internal class of the Dapper, which can be directly typecast to `IDictionary<string,object>`, since it implements `IDictionary` interface. All that you have to do is:

```
var a = db.Query(query, null, null, true, null, CommandType.Text).Select(x => x as IDictionary<string,object>);
```

Now result would be of type `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>`, which can be used to extract all the required information, since column names are keys and respective row value is the value of each element in the `IEnumerable`.

Also check, this may too work, but I am not sure:

```
 var a = (IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,object>>)db.Query(query, null, null, true, null, CommandType.Text);
```

Comment: It returns as same DapperRow. as above.

Comment: You can typecast, DapperRow is only for the debugger

Comment: TypeCast to my Entity Class?

Comment: No Typecast to `IDictionary<string,object>` as I have shown, then you have to work at creating your typed entity

Comment: What's the problem in doing so, its straight forward, in case you already know type then use `Query<T>`, otherwise I don't see much choice here

Comment: Because sometimes, we need less columns sometimes more.. in that case we have to take all properties in account.. that's why